# How to analyze Node.js profile file on Mac?

Tags: node.js, profiling

I am using Node.js 8.3. And I use `node --prof server.js` to profile my app. I get some file with name like *xxxx*-v8.log.

I tried to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-tick-processor and https://github.com/sidorares/node-tick to analyze the file. I am interested to see the CPU profile.

But the output is like this, which is not very helpful:

```
[Bottom up (heavy) profile]:
  Note: percentage shows a share of a particular caller in the total
  amount of its parent calls.
  Callers occupying less than 2.0% are not shown.

   ticks parent  name
  65591   59.5%  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
  42621   65.0%    /usr/local/bin/node

  16632   15.1%  /usr/local/bin/node
   5544   33.3%    /usr/local/bin/node

   5888    5.3%  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
   5875   99.8%    /usr/local/bin/node

   2702    2.4%  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
   2284   84.5%    /usr/local/bin/node


 [Top down (heavy) profile]:
  Note: callees occupying less than 0.1% are not shown.

  inclusive      self           name
  ticks   total  ticks   total
  68106   61.7%  11088   10.1%  /usr/local/bin/node
  42617   38.6%  42617   38.6%    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
   5875    5.3%   5875    5.3%    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
   5548    5.0%   5538    5.0%    /usr/local/bin/node
   2284    2.1%   2284    2.1%    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    337    0.3%    337    0.3%    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    303    0.3%    303    0.3%    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib

  22970   20.8%  22970   20.8%  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib

    418    0.4%    418    0.4%  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
```

Is there any other tool to analyze the output file? I want to see something that shows bottleneck functions or at least locate the line number for me. I have tried `v8-profiler` and its the output file needs to be loaded on Chrome dev tool. But the format looks different. I am not sure if I am still able to analyze the `-v8.log` file.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no problem with your tool usage. The trouble here is that the contribution of CPU consumption from `named` JS functions are too small to be visible in the heavy profile. Please note the caveat in your profile output (callees occupying less than 0.1% are not shown.)

Consider my code:

```
var x = 10;
function foo() {
  while (true) {
    x++;
  }
}
foo();
```

And it's prof output. As you can see, the script, the function and it's line # appears, as the predominant CPU eater.

```
 [Unknown]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
     13    0.3%

 [Shared libraries]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
     57    1.3%    0.0%  /usr/local/bin/node
      6    0.1%    0.0%  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
      2    0.0%    0.0%  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
      1    0.0%    0.0%  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
      1    0.0%    0.0%  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib

 [JavaScript]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
   4177   98.1%   99.7%  LazyCompile: *foo /Users/gireesh/a.js:2:13
      1    0.0%    0.0%  Stub: BinaryOpWithAllocationSiteStub

 [C++]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name

 [GC]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
      2    0.0%

 [Bottom up (heavy) profile]:
  Note: percentage shows a share of a particular caller in the total
  amount of its parent calls.
  Callers occupying less than 2.0% are not shown.

   ticks parent  name
   4177   98.1%  LazyCompile: *foo /Users/gireesh/a.js:2:13
   4177  100.0%    LazyCompile: *foo /Users/gireesh/a.js:2:13
   4177  100.0%      Function: ~<anonymous> /Users/gireesh/a.js:1:11
   4177  100.0%        Function: ~Module._compile module.js:526:37
   4177  100.0%          Function: ~Module._extensions..js module.js:578:37
   4177  100.0%            Function: ~Module.load module.js:494:33
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does that mean I can do nothing to improve my app performance based on the profile? I am not an expert of Node. This CPU usage could probably be caused by doing something inappropriate in using Node.js methods that have direct access to the V8 engine. I am giving up now. Can't see how to improve my app at this stage.

Comment: Please don't give up so fast! use `-j` flag to the tick processor and see that your JS profile has come into the highlight, discarding the VM, compiler and other runtime state.

Comment: Thanks but I don't see a `-j` option in `node-tick-processor ` or `node-tick`. Not sure how to use it correctly. Besides, if the functions that I need to change are occupying less than 0.1% of the CPU it makes no sense for me to continue improving it. Unless there are some tricks that are hiding the real culprits from my sight.

Comment: sorry for the delay, here is the info:

bash$ node_modules/node-tick-processor/bin/node-tick-processor --help
Cmdline args: [options] [log-file-name]
Default log file name is "v8.log".

Options:
  -j, --js            Show only ticks from JS VM state
  -g, --gc            Show only ticks from GC VM state
  -c, --compiler      Show only ticks from COMPILER VM state
  -o, --other         Show only ticks from OTHER VM state
  -e, --external      Show only ticks from EXTERNAL VM state

https://github.com/drewfish/node-tick-processor/blob/master/bin/node-tick-processor#L2891

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I have tried using `-j` option with `node-tick-processor` and the result is basically the same thing as before.

Comment: thanks for confirmation, that would essentially mean that (i) your JS code execution time is very tiny compared to other part of the virtual machine (i) there is nothing much we can do in the JS code to improve the performance, as the overall performance is a function of other artifacts in the virtual machine, not the JS code.

Comment: I am thinking of the same thing. I have actually tried `v8-profiler` and recorded a "cpuprofile" file for Chrome dev tool. This one gives a result that points the main usage to the `timers.js` file in Node.js. This project is very CPU intensive. It seems I can't do much about it.

Comment: @newguy - Is it possible for you to bring this up to `https://github.com/nodejs/help` where wider node.js maintainers can have a look, probably with more details about your application? thanks!